# How do I change the value of a bound WPF class variable?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, xaml, binding

I am new to WPF/XAML.

I am making a scrolling marquee using a demo I found online.
It is WinForms using a HostedElement WPF custom User Control.

I was able to setup a class called MyModelView so that I can bind the text value of a textblock to a variable I control (MyTextProperty).

But I can't figure out how to change the variable. My goal is to have a textbox you can enter text into and it will bind to the textblock value and change it while the program is running.

I am not able to do this, which I am trying to do (Change bound variable to TextBox1 value - it is not a valid reference to the variable... what is?):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    MyViewModel.MyTextProperty = TextBox1.text
End Sub
```

How do I reference that class variable to change the text? I am missing something.

**MyViewModel.vb**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        Me.myTextValue = "WINNING!!!"
    End Sub

    Private myTextValue As String = String.Empty
    Public Property MyTextProperty() As String
        Get
            Return Me.myTextValue
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.myTextValue = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyTextProperty")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Scrolling Marque.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScrollingMarquee"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:interopdemo="clr-namespace:InteropDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MarqueeScroll">
            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="spMarquee" 
                From="1500"  To="-500" 
                Duration="0:0:0:7" />
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <interopdemo:MyViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <StackPanel x:Name="spMarquee" Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="Auto">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,60,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello Scrolling Text!" Foreground="Firebrick" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,0,60,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Ticker 2000!" Foreground="Red" FontSize="28" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0,80,0"/>
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Form1.vb**

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        ElementHost1.Visible = True
        Dim storyRunMarquee As Storyboard = ScrollingMarquee1.FindResource("MarqueeScroll")
        storyRunMarquee.Begin()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I've tried referencing the variable but can't make it work. The scrolling animation displays as "Winning! Hello Scrolling Text! Ticker 2000!" But I'm trying to change the bound "Winning!" text.

Comment: You write about "My goal is to have a textbox you can enter text into ..." , but I don't see any `TextBox` in posted example.

Comment: It's Winforms, so it's on Form1.vb which I didn't post the designer back-end code for. The textblock is called TextBox1. You're seeing XAML in my question because on my form I have an embedded ElementHost which is hosting the XAML UserControl. So this is Winforms with embedded WPF element.

Comment: What is `MyModelView` from `MyModelView.MyTextProperty = TextBox1.text`?

Comment: Typo - fixed. What I want to do is MyViewModel.MyTextProperty = TextBox1.text but I can't reference it in that way. I need to know how to change it. The variable is bound and works in the animation, I just don't know how to reference. Thanks

Comment: Side note - for convenience, you may wish to use the `<CallerMemberName>` attribute on the `propertyName` argument of `NotifyPropertyChanged`, then you don't need to write it out at the call site, the compiler will automatically fill it in for you.  (When you do this, it needs to become an `Optional` parameter.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
<Grid.DataContext>
   <interopdemo:MyViewModel/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

Declare a member variable in the form to hold reference to the view model object:

```
Private scrollerViewModel As MyViewModel
```

Instantiate an object of class `MyViewModel` in `Form1_Load` and set it as a `DataContext` for user control.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
   Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

   ElementHost1.Visible = True

   scrollerViewModel = New MyViewModel
   ScrollingMarquee1.DataContext = scrollerViewModel

   Dim storyRunMarquee As Storyboard = ScrollingMarquee1.FindResource("MarqueeScroll")
   storyRunMarquee.Begin()

End Sub
```

Modify property:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    scrollerViewModel.MyTextProperty = TextBox1.text
End Sub
```

Comment: Syntax can be wrong, I'm not from VB world.

Comment: Thank you for this input It is headed in the right direction I think. When I test the modify property (scrollerViewModel.MyTextProperty = TextBox1.Text), I get a runtime error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' But you did show me another way to instantiate which I think is closer to the goal.

Comment: scrollerViewModel.MyTextProperty = "Hello" - this works if I put it into Form1_Load. Is it possible it is out of scope when I put it into the Sub TextBox1_TextChanged?

Comment: OK wierd. If I put scrollerViewModel.MyTextProperty = TextBox1.Text into a sub for Textbox1_textchanged it does not work (runtime error as noted above) but if I put it into a sub for Button1_Click it works and changes the text scrolling in real time! You did it! I think I can handle this from here! Thank you so much!

Comment: See also [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to cast the datacontext of ScrollingMarquee1 as MyViewModel

```
 CType(ScrollingMarquee1.DataContext, MyViewModel).MyTextProperty = TextBox1.text
```